# Как отфильтровать данные одной таблицы, используя данные другой таблицы?

Tags: sql

**photos:**
[id, user_id, (...url)]
|1, 1| - фотография #1, принадлежащая #1 пользователю
|2, 4| - фотография #2, принадлежащая #4 пользователю
|3, 2| - фотография #3, принадлежащая #2 пользователю
|4, 3| - фотография #4, принадлежащая #3 пользователю
|5, 5| - фотография #5, принадлежащая #5 пользователю

**viewed:**
[id, user_id, photo_id]
|1, 2, 4| - #2 пользователь посмотрел фотографию #4, принадлежащую #3 пользователю
|2, 3, 2| - #3 пользователь посмотрел фотографию #2, принадлежащую #4 пользователю
|2, 3, 5| - #3 пользователь посмотрел фотографию #5, принадлежащую #5 пользователю

Как среди этих данных получить только те фотографии, которые НЕ смотрел #3 пользователь? А так же попробовать отфильтровать фотки самого юзера #3, то есть фотка #4 (mysql)
То есть:
**result:**
[id, user_id, (...url)]
|1, 1| - фотография #1, принадлежащая #1 пользователю
|3, 2| - фотография #3, принадлежащая #2 пользователю

Как понимаю, нужно как-то тыкать join'ы, но у меня всё ещё никак это не может нормально связаться в голове. Хотелось бы посмотреть решение знающих людей. Спасибо.

Comment: Left join и на where viewed.id is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я верно понимаю вас, то можно вот так вот, надеюсь с синтаксисом не ошибся, идея в том что выбираем все уникальные фото которые НЕ смотрел пользователь 3

```
select distinct id
from photos
where id not in (select photo_id from viewed where user_id = 3)
```

Или вариант с join

```
select *
from viewed v left join photos p on p.user_id = v.user_id
```

Ну а дальше фильтруете как надо